# how to uninstall ns-2.35 from ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-uninstall

i am new to ns2, i'd like to uninstall my ns-allinone-2.35 package, from ubuntu 12.04LTS

i followed these steps:

```
sudo aptitude purge ns-allinone-2.35


sudo apt-get purge ns-allinone-2.35


sudo dpkg -P ns-allinone-2.35.
```

but after going through these procedures too , i'm able to execute ns,

i'd like to how to uninstall a complete ns-allinone-2.35 package

Yours Solutions are Welcome!!!!!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: try with `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove ns-allinone-2.35`

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install autoremove ns-allinone-2.35`

If that doesn't work, skip the `install` bit.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
sudo apt-get remove ns2
```

Comment: @Milad: Could you please [edit] your answer and help the OP to fish instead of giving him a fish?  (that is: explain to him why he has to do this?)  Furthermore, also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future before the system decides to delete your answer automatically because of low quality... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The package with the name *ns-allinone-2.35* doesn't exist in the Ubuntu standard repositories. So I assume that you mean the package "ns2".

```
Package: ns2
Priority: optional
Section: universe/net
...
Description-en: Discrete event simulator targeted at networking research
 Provides substantial support for simulation of TCP, routing,
 and multicast protocols over wired and wireless (local and satellite)
 networks.
 Ns-2 is written in C++ and an Object oriented version of Tcl called OTcl.
...
```

You can remove it completely including the system-wide configuration files by running:

```
sudo apt-get purge ns2
```

If you do not want to remove the configuration files, then use

```
sudo apt-get remove ns2
```